# What is the operating humidity of the RasPi?

Tags: pi-2, pi-b

I am curious what the relative operating humidity of the RasPi is. There is a lot of information about measuring humidity with the RasPi, but I haven't come across any information about the max operating humidity of the RasPi is.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this graph ([Instructables Image)](http://cdn.instructables.com/F28/E8B1/HOUG1FCP/F28E8B1HOUG1FCP.LARGE.jpg), it commonly runs around 80% to 90% at normal.

[image: Temp. C / Orange Temperature / Humidity]

Here's the original project that measures the temperature and humidity. It should be step 9: [Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Temperature-Humidity-Network-Monitor/).

The GitHub repo for the code can be found at: [jervine/rpi-temp-humid-monitor](https://github.com/jervine/rpi-temp-humid-monitor)

Comment: If would be good if you could provide a context for that .jpg graph.  As it appears right now, it may or may not actually have anything to do with the pi.

Comment: I'll update the link, the only reason I didn't was because it was a step-by-step humidity meter for the Pi. @goldilocks

Comment: Although it commonly running "at 20-40%" makes sense, since that is low to normal atmospheric humidity most places,  I think **your conclusion that "80%" is the max is incorrect.**  I think that was *the highest reading* from *a temp/humidity monitoring station build using a pi*, but the purpose of the monitoring was not to protect the pi itself.   I'd guess it should be okay above 80 or 90% humidity since this is not all that unusual some places (just not around here, so I don't know for sure).

Comment: I completely understand what you are getting to. I'd say the same now that I think about it, so I'll update the post.

Comment: Thank you both for posting. I came across that post, and I wasn't sure if that would be the actual max operational humidity. I was hoping to have some official documentation, but this will do! Thanks again!

Comment: A lot of our Pi's are located in open buildings (pillars with a roof on top).  Weather.com tells me `dry` season months have ~75% humidity, others ~85%.  Data shows it peaked to 96% a couple days ago.  On top of that we have quite some beachfront venue installations.  Metal parts (LAN+USB) might get a little bit oxidized but haven't seen any issues really.

Comment: No problem. @NotaPieGuy